# How to generate unique number for each address?

Tags: java, algorithm

I have couple of addresses like this -

```
19.22.145.103
20.52.175.104
19.92.192.102
11.20.175.108
```

I want to create a unique number for each of the above IP Address. I was doing it this way -

Sum of each octet 19 + 22 + 145 + 103 = 289 as the unique number.

But by this we might have same number for some IP Addresses since we are just summing the octet.

```
19.22.145.103 = 289
20.52.175.104 = 351
19.22.147.101 = 289
11.20.175.108 = 314
```

As you can see above, `289` is coming for two IP Address with my algorithm for summing the octets which is not what I want. I need a unique number which is short data type for each ip address.

Is there any better way to do this with some other formula? I thought my algorithm will guarantee uniqueness.

Comment: Why not just treat it as a 32 bit number?

Comment: You can't map from an IPv4 address to a short uniquely - one has 32 bits, the other has 16. You will always have collisions.

Comment: @AndyTurner Can you explain why we can't map? Didn't understand fully.

Comment: I don't think OP means short as in the data type, but short as in simple.

Comment: An IPv4 address has 32 bits - it can have one of 2^32 values. A short has 16 bits - it can have 2^16 values. There is simply more information in one than the other. You can store the IPv4 address in an int uniquely, because that has 32 bits - and actually that's how it is transmitted in the IP header.

Comment: @Biffen the OP states below that he "was looking for a number which is short (16 bits)".

Comment: @AndyTurner Yes, I saw that. So my earlier comment was wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An IPv4 address is simply a 32 bit number. The `aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd` is just a human readable formatting.

If you just have the octets you can transform it back to a unique 32 bit number as follows:

```
octet1 << 24 | octet2 << 16 | octet3 << 8 | octet4
```

Each octet is 8 bit (`00` - `FF`). You get the unique 32 bit integer by putting them side by side. The easiest way to do this is to shift them in place and or them together:

```
octet4   --------------------------.
octet3   -------------------.      |
octet2   ----------.        |      |
octet1   ---.      |        |      |
            |      |        |      |
         byte 1  byte 2  byte 3  byte 4
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation so that I can understand little bit? And also how does it guarantee uniqueness?

Comment: @user1950349 an IPv4 is a 32 bit number. That's how they're treated internally by routers, etc. The textual representation is useful for humans because it's easier to read. So this above just transforms back the readable representation to the binary format, which was chosen to make it fast for computers to use IP addresses in the first place.

Comment: user1950349, The reason it is unique is because none of the octets overlap in the resulting 32-bit number.

Comment: @aioobe Very well understood. In my case I was looking for a number which is short (16 bits). I don't want to hold all the information for that IP Address. Just a unique way to represent that IP Address. For short, maximum value it can have is 32767 right so we can have some formula which generate unique number between 1 and 32767 for each of the IP Address so that it doesn't collide. In our case we will not have 32767 IP Address at all. May be just 1000 max. That's why I mentioned short data type in the question. Since we have another program which reads this number as short data type only.

Comment: Ok, well, there are 2^32 different IP-addresses in total, so unless you can enumerate all the ~1000 IP-addresses that you want to cover in advance, there's no way to create a formula that maps an arbitrary IP-address to a unique 16 bit number. It's called the [Pigeonhole principle](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle).

Answer (score 2):

If you know the set of possible IP addresses in advance **and** if the size of that set is less than what can be held in a short (less than 2^16) then you can look at implementing a Perfect Hash Function that is guarenteed to map each of your IP addresses onto a unique 16 bit value.

> A hash function for which there are no collisions is called a "perfect
>   hash function" (PHF). A PHF for which the hash table has no holes in
>   it (that is, the hash table is only as big as the search list) is
>   called a "minimal perfect hash function" (MPHF).

There are a variety of tools avialble to generate Perfect Hash Functions and a good article [here](http://www.drdobbs.com/architecture-and-design/generating-perfect-hash-functions/184404506).

You will have to think about the implications of this approach - if the set of IP addresses changes then the chances are that your PHF will no longer be perfect and fixing this will involve regenerating the PHF and changing the code.  As stated above an IPv4 address already has a unique 32 bit representation and I'd use that if at all posible.